# Vuetify 1.1.11 Types are not Working in VSCode

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js

VSCode always warns me that Vuetify has no definitions.
I am importing from `import Vuetify from 'vuetify/es5/components/Vuetify'`

Any clue?

Regards

Comment: What wrong with `import Vuetify from 'vuetify'`?

Comment: It compiles but it does not work (vue does not mount to the root element). Plus, importing other components one by one also does not work.